# Extract AICs from an ARIMA using a nested loop

Tags: r, for-loop, time-series, arima

I am trying to extract AICs & BICs from an ARIMA estimation with different
combinations of p & q (p=0,1,2,3
and q=0,1.2,3). I have tried using the following code, unsucessfully.

> 

```
code: storage1 <- numeric(16) for (p in 0:3){

>     for (q in 0:3){
>  
>     storage1[p]  <- arima(x,order=c(p,0,q), method="ML")} } storage1$aic
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use `expand.grid()` to get all combinations of `p` and `q`, and apply them to your arima model, i.e.

```
apply(expand.grid(p, q), 1, function(i) arima(d1$cnt, order = c(i[1], 0, i[2]), method = "ML")$aic)

#[1] 47222.43 38589.14 36935.33 36118.44 42569.73 35183.35 35141.13 35143.02 39448.38 35142.96 35142.58 35142.60
```

Comment: Thank you. I get the different estimations, but I also get a warning message saying:

Comment: Thank you. The code  gives me different estimations of the model, but I also get a warning message saying:                                                                            
   
`1: In arima(data$x, order = c(i[1], 0, i[2]), method = "ML") :
  possible convergence problem: optim gave code = 1`

Is there a specific reason to that?

Comment: The warning has nothing to do with the solution. Saying `optim` with `code = 1` it means that max iterations were met. So you ll need to change that. There is an argument in arima called `optim.control` which you should play around with